# SQLite UWP - retreive one row data returns null

Tags: sqlite, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to tretreive data from my `SQLite` database in `UWP`, but only one specific line. Now, It works for multiple lines, but still not for one single line... This is the code I'm using;

```
public static Participant GetParticipant(int klasse_id, int start_number)
        {
            Participant res = new Participant();
            try
            {
                string sSQL = @"SELECT * FROM participants WHERE class_id = " + klasse_id + " AND start_number = " + start_number + " LIMIT 1;";
                ISQLiteStatement dbState = dbConnection.Prepare(sSQL);
                // Get the records
                if (SQLiteResult.DONE == dbState.Step())
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(dbState["pilot_firstName"].ToString());
                    // Set the new value
                    res = new Participant()
                    {
                        pilot_firstName = dbState["pilot_firstName"].ToString(),
                        pilot_lastName = dbState["pilot_lastName"].ToString(),
                        pilot_club = dbState["pilot_club"].ToString(),
                        pilot_license = dbState["pilot_license"].ToString(),
                        pilot_tel = dbState["pilot_tel"].ToString(),
                        navigator_firstName = dbState["navigator_firstName"].ToString(),
                        navigator_lastName = dbState["navigator_lastName"].ToString(),
                        navigator_club = dbState["navigator_club"].ToString(),
                        navigator_license = dbState["navigator_license"].ToString(),
                        navigator_tel = dbState["navigator_tel"].ToString(),
                        is_stopped = Int32.Parse(dbState["is_stopped"].ToString()),
                        class_id = Int32.Parse(dbState["class_id"].ToString()),
                        start_id = Int32.Parse(dbState["start_id"].ToString()),
                        star_nmbr = Int32.Parse(dbState["start_number"].ToString())
                    };
                }
                return res;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

I get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` every time... But when I execute my SQL query plain, I get valid data;

[image: Query result]

My Class for `Participant` looks like this:

```
public class Participant
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string pilot_firstName { get; set; }
        public string pilot_lastName { get; set; }
        public string pilot_club { get; set; }
        public string pilot_license { get; set; }
        public string pilot_tel { get; set; }
        public string navigator_firstName { get; set; }
        public string navigator_lastName { get; set; }
        public string navigator_club { get; set; }
        public string navigator_license { get; set; }
        public string navigator_tel { get; set; }
        public int is_stopped { get; set; }
        public int class_id { get; set; }
        public int start_id { get; set; }
        public int star_nmbr { get; set; }
    }
```

Does anyone see what is wrong here?

Comment: on which line? maybe try to inspect ll the results of dbState one by one?

Comment: If I do a debug, it crashes on `Debug.WriteLine(dbState["pilot_firstName"].ToString());`, when I run the code without that dbState[item], it just prints the debug line and crashes when it reaches the dbState[]...

Comment: well something is wrong in the way you do the query and get the result. is there a execute something maybe you need to do first? clearly dbState[pilot_firstName] is giving null result.

just curious what kind of app?

Comment: Well, it's an app for a hobby of mine, (UWP desktop), but the Query executed in a DB browser and returns the values, so why is this not returning anything? That is the strange thing here...

Comment: curous what kind of app since  i fly myself ;)

Comment: It's with a car, not a plane haha... It's called 'rittensport', in Belgium.... Navigate with your car using a roadbook and then write down found letters etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
public static Participant GetParticipant(int klasse_id, int start_number)
    {
        try
        {
            string sSQL = @"SELECT * FROM participants WHERE class_id = " + klasse_id + " AND start_number = " + start_number + " LIMIT 1;";
            ISQLiteStatement dbState = dbConnection.Prepare(sSQL);
            // Get the records
            while (SQLiteResult.ROW == dbState.Step())
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(dbState["pilot_firstName"].ToString());
                // Set the new value
                var res = new Participant()
                {
                    pilot_firstName = dbState["pilot_firstName"].ToString(),
                    pilot_lastName = dbState["pilot_lastName"].ToString(),
                    pilot_club = dbState["pilot_club"].ToString(),
                    pilot_license = dbState["pilot_license"].ToString(),
                    pilot_tel = dbState["pilot_tel"].ToString(),
                    navigator_firstName = dbState["navigator_firstName"].ToString(),
                    navigator_lastName = dbState["navigator_lastName"].ToString(),
                    navigator_club = dbState["navigator_club"].ToString(),
                    navigator_license = dbState["navigator_license"].ToString(),
                    navigator_tel = dbState["navigator_tel"].ToString(),
                    is_stopped = Int32.Parse(dbState["is_stopped"].ToString()),
                    class_id = Int32.Parse(dbState["class_id"].ToString()),
                    start_id = Int32.Parse(dbState["start_id"].ToString()),
                    star_nmbr = Int32.Parse(dbState["start_number"].ToString())
                };
        return res;
            }
            return null; // In case if there is no result
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you have a sample you can share so can have better look?

Comment: So I did not update the database, now I get another error, using your code: `Input string was not in a correct format.` But `Debug.WriteLine(dbState["pilot_firstName"].ToString());` gives the correct value (it crashes on the `var res = new Participant()..`

Comment: try all the dbState["start_number"] one by one.. or write it as : res.pilot_firstName = dbState["pilot_firstName"].toString(); one of the Int parsing is not going correct; i think it is startid

Comment: Ow gash, that type of me... Start_id is a string, not an int, so when I tried to make it in the object, an int can't hold a string, so it broke.... Thanks for the answer haha